# How can I create data table component by Polymer

Tags: polymer

How can I make a data table component by using polymer?
This data table component have feature like datatables.net , ng-grid, ng-table does.

Comment: I realize this topic is closed, but as many others are already promoting their components here, I’ll add one more to the list. Namely "vaadin-grid":

https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-grid

Answer (score 2):

It might be good to start from an example like [aha-table](https://github.com/liuwenchao/aha-table). It has several good examples of how to use polymer's expressions to do something dynamic like a datagrid. Other examples may be found on [CustomElements.io](http://customelements.io/).

Answer (score 1):

The best I have found is sortable-table by stevenrskelton

github: https://github.com/stevenrskelton/sortable-table

also on http://component.kitchen/components

Answer (score 1):

handsontable has a project in a polymer flavor, which may be of interest.

https://github.com/handsontable/hot-table